# Button works when the required fields are not filled after you fill and delete what is written

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a page where if first name and last name is not filled addAddress button will not work. This piece of code works perfectly if you press addAddress button it asks for those required fields to be filled. When you will it, it works, but if you just fill it and the delete what you have written, button will work again. I do not get the idea what is the problem?

```
    self.addAddress = function () {
    if (self.FirstName() != undefined && self.LastName() != undefined) {
        self.selectedAddress(new Address(true));
    }

    else {
        self.errors.showAllMessages();

    }
};
```

Comment: is it just typo or are you checking the FirstName twice?

Comment: it is no more undefined but empty string

Comment: @BeardedMan how can I change the if statement so it will work normal?

Comment: @BeardedMan it is typo, my baad

Comment: I cannot check it now myself, but won't just changing the undefined to '' (empty string) do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you delete it it is no longer undefined but empty string, so checking empty string should do the trick

```
self.addAddress = function () {
if (self.FirstName() !== '' && self.LastName() !== '') {
    self.selectedAddress(new Address(true));
}

else {
    self.errors.showAllMessages();

}
```

Comment: Consider updating your answer to either use `!==`, or the `!!` idiom. Currently, e.g., if `FirstName` accidentally got the number zero as its value the code would not work as expected.

Comment: Also this answer encourage using ko validation in a manner that is bad practice

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is to define a validation group and check against that.  Your way of doing it only uses variation for display messages..

Define group

```
this.errors = ko.validation.group(this)
```

Check it for valid

```
this.errors().length === 0
```